# Golang grpc: how to recover the grpc server from panic?

Tags: go, crash, grpc

I have a handler like this:

```
func (daemon *Daemon) List(item string) (map[string][]string, error) {
      panic("this is a panic")
      ...
```

I just want to recover this potential panic, so in my grpc server I wrote:

```
// Serve serves gRPC request by goroutines
func (s *ServerRPC) Serve(addr string) error {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            glog.Errorf("Recovered from err: ", err)
        }
    }()

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        glog.Fatalf("Failed to listen %s: %v", addr, err)
        return err
    }

    return s.server.Serve(l)
}
```

But it does not capture the panic, I thought it was because my panic happened in child goroutines? If so, how can I recover my grpc server from crashing properly?

Comment: Doing the same defer-recover in each function would is the brute-force way, of course, but leaving this open in case there's a gRPC-specific way. (Could factor it into `defer recoverPanic()` if you have to do it the verbose way.)

Comment: https://github.com/kazegusuri/grpc-panic-handler looks promising!

Comment: I wonder why this is not implemented in GRPC itself?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the recovery interceptor in the [Golang gRPC Middlewares](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware) package. It recovers from panics in the request Goroutine and returns them as an internal gRPC error.

```golang
myServer := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.StreamInterceptor(grpc_middleware.ChainStreamServer(
        grpc_zap.StreamServerInterceptor(zapLogger),
        grpc_auth.StreamServerInterceptor(myAuthFunction),
        grpc_recovery.StreamServerInterceptor(),
    )),
    grpc.UnaryInterceptor(grpc_middleware.ChainUnaryServer(
        grpc_zap.UnaryServerInterceptor(zapLogger),
        grpc_auth.UnaryServerInterceptor(myAuthFunction),
        grpc_recovery.UnaryServerInterceptor(),
    )),
)
```

Comment: Is it required to put a panic recovery interceptor at the end of a ChainUnaryServer ? 
Why in the example here https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware#middleware it is a first member of a chain?

Comment: Placing the recovery interceptor at the top of the chain will mean panics originating from the other interceptors (as opposed to the API application code itself) will also be recovered from.

Comment: Panic handler should be the first one https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/pull/414/files

Comment: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/pull/464